# Why does my executable fail to link to my shared library function when it doesn't have export attributes?

Tags: c++, cmake

#### Context

I'm trying to build an executable with CMake.

I have a linker error when linking a shared library to an executable in the same project.

**How can I link the library as a shared library and build?**

#### Problem

This is the output from CMake.

```
[main] Building folder: CMake-Shared 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build d:/dev/Cpp/CMake/CMake-Shared/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [1/3  33% :: 0.319] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Lib.dir/Lib/src/hello.cc.obj
[build] [2/3  66% :: 0.408] Linking CXX shared library Lib.dll
[build] [3/3 100% :: 0.476] Linking CXX executable Main.exe
[build] FAILED: Main.exe 
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE -fuse-ld=lld-link -nostartfiles -nostdlib -g -Xclang -gcodeview -O0 -D_DEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrtd -Xlinker /subsystem:console CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main/src/main.cc.obj -o Main.exe -Xlinker /MANIFEST:EMBED -Xlinker /implib:Main.lib -Xlinker /pdb:Main.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0   Lib.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames  && cd ."
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: __cdecl Hello::Hello(class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>>)
[build] >>> referenced by D:\dev\Cpp\CMake\CMake-Shared\Main\src\main.cc:8
[build] >>>               CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main/src/main.cc.obj:(main)
[build] 
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>> __cdecl Hello::Say(class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>>)
[build] >>> referenced by D:\dev\Cpp\CMake\CMake-Shared\Main\src\main.cc:9
[build] >>>               CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main/src/main.cc.obj:(main)
[build] clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build d:/dev/Cpp/CMake/CMake-Shared/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1 and signal: null
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

#### Code

```
PS D:\dev\Cpp\CMake\CMake-Shared> tree /f
D:.
│  CMakeLists.txt
│
├─Lib
│  ├─include
│  │      hello.h
│  │
│  └─src
│          hello.cc
│
└─Main
    └─src
            main.cc
```

```
# ./CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(sample CXX)

add_library(Lib SHARED
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Lib/src/hello.cc
)
target_include_directories(Lib INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Lib/include
)

add_executable(Main
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Main/src/main.cc
)

target_link_libraries(Main Lib)
# target_link_directories(Main PUBLIC $<TARGET_FILE:Lib>)
# target_link_directories(Main PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Lib)
```

```
// ./Lib/include/hello.h

#ifndef __HELLO_H__
#define __HELLO_H__

#include <string>

class Hello {
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    Hello(std::string name);
    
    std::string Say(std::string message);
};

#endif // __HELLO_H__
```

```
// ./Lib/src/hello.cc

#include "../include/hello.h"

Hello::Hello(std::string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

std::string Hello::Say(std::string message) {
    return message + ", " + name + '.';
}
```

```
// ./Main/src/main.cc

#include <iostream>

#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Hello hello("John");
    cout << hello.Say("Hi") << endl;
}
```

#### Version

- OS: Windows 11 Home 64 bits
- CMake: 3.24.2
- Ninja: 1.11.1
- Clang: 15.0.2

  - Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  - Thread model: posix
  - InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
- VSCode: 1.73.0

#### Attempt

I used `target_link_directories` but it didn't work.

I can link if I change SHARED into STATIC of `add_library`.

I tried to make the #include path in main.cc relative but it didn't work.

Comment: On Windows you normally need to explicitly export symbols from a DLL and import them into your main executable. Look up Microsoft-specific attributes `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`. You may also want to try changing the target from `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` to `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` (add `-target ...` to the compiler flags) without changing the code.

Comment: CMake provides [a helper module to define cross-platform export macros](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html). You may find it helpful. Pretty good job you did providing details to reproduce your issue!

Comment: Thank you, n.m. and david-fong!
I could solve the problem by using `generate_export_header` and inserting dll macro.